# window.onload not calling function

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

With this index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is the body</p>
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this main.js

```
console.log("main.js ran");

function render() {
    console.log("render ran");
}

window.onload = render;
```

I would expect the console output to show:

```
main.js ran
render ran
```

The "main.js ran" shows as expected, but "render ran" doesn't get logged.  The render function never gets called.  Why not?

Comment: Um, strange. All looks fine to me.

Comment: How are you loading `main.js`? I suspect you're loading it after the window has been loaded, so it's too late for `window.onload` functions to run.

Comment: @Bermar, good find but why would main.js ran appear in the console if Vocalionecho has linked the wrong javascript file. From the code snippet both `console.log()` are in the same file.

Comment: try adding <body onload="render();">

Comment: @NewToJS That's why I think the problem is that he's loading the file after `window.onload` has run.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, i seen your post appear after I submitted my comment. This is a strange issue though, I have never hit this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[RequireJS loads the `data-main` script asynchronously](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main).  Thus there is a race condition between the page loading and main.js loading.  If main.js finishes loading first, `window.onload` will be set and you will see "render ran".  If the page finishes loading first, you won't.  Which of these two outcomes occurs is indeterminate in general, but since the example page you've given is extremely short, it will usually finish loading before main.js has been fetched from the server.

If you want your module to run after the page loads, you can add a dependency on the [`domReady` module](https://github.com/requirejs/domReady):

```
<script src="require.js"></script> <!-- note, no 'data-main' -->
<script>require( ['main'], function() {} );</script>
```

main.js:

```
define(['domReady!'], function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: this worked exactly.  just for anyone else new to web programming, here's a bit more follow up.

Comment: The problem was that the page was finishing loading before the main.js could set the window.onload.  require.js has an affiliated tool called domReady that allows you to set what amounts to a callback that gets called after the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with RequireJS and the fact that the page is already loaded. RequireJS should already be waiting for all the files to load so use the below code.

Example:

```
console.log("main.js ran");

function render() {
    console.log("render ran");
}

render();
```

If you are trying to wait for an HTML element to load use jQuery:

```
//will run once the page DOM is ready
$(element).ready(function(){
   ...
});

//will run once the entire page is
//loaded including images and iframes
$(element).load(function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: `$(element).ready()` is the same as `$(document).ready()`. Individual elements don't have a `ready` event.

Comment: If he's using `RequireJS`, doesn't it have its own feature to run functions after loading a particular file?