# Typescript window.onload not being called after adding requirejs for phaser game

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, phaser-framework, js-amd

I am trying to make a game with phaser and Typescript. I followed the instructions [here](http://phaser.io/tutorials/how-to-use-phaser-with-typescript) and it worked initialy. The problems came when I tried to modularise my code using AMD and requirejs

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Resonate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="phaser.js"></script>
    <script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.20/minified/require.js" data-main="app"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RESONATE</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Player.ts

```
export class Player {

    color: string;

    constructor() {
        this.color = "#0000ff";
    }
}
```

### app.ts

```
import player = require("Player");

class PhaserDemo {

    game: Phaser.Game;

    constructor() {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.WEBGL, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create });
    }

    preload() {
        this.game.load.image('phaser_run', 'run.png');
    }

    create() {
        console.log("Before");
        var p = new player.Player();
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor = p.color;
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    console.log("ONLOAD");
    var game = new PhaserDemo();
};
```

Now when I load it up window.onload is never called, I tried following 
[window.onload not calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596886/window-onload-not-calling-function)
for the Javascript solution but I can't get it to work in typescript.

Also here is the generated Javascript if you want to take a look https://gist.github.com/koreus7/06bee4a30d22bdc76d62

Comment: The part about the race condition between RequireJS and window.onload in the linked question is still true -- you can't count on your script running before that event fires. You should be addressing that problem.

Comment: The problem is that the Javascript in [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596886/window-onload-not-calling-function) will not convert to typescript. I have tried just using that solution but I don't know how to call typescript from javascript.

Comment: Basically my question is how do I implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596886/window-onload-not-calling-function) solution in typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> for the Javascript solution but I can't get it to work in typescript.

Basically if the window is already loaded attaching to `window.onload` will not call the attached function.

Check for `document.readyState === "complete"`. Alternatively use something like jquery ready : https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is caused by the require.js loader, it is without I explicitly know it a bit similar to jspm system.js , and so we don't need to ensure that the window is loaded because the loader already has ensured that.

I just removed the window.onload and it worked fine :)