# onLoad events not firing after switching to require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I currently have my JS split into several scripts, all in the `js/script` directory. Each script has a structure similar to the following example:

```
var game=(function(){
    //inner functions here, i.e.:
    function _tick(){
        return "something";
    }

    function _server_time(){
        return "something else";
    }

    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        console.log("happening?");
    });

    var _ext={
        tick:_tick,
        server_time: _server_time
    };

    return _ext;
})();
```

Functions in other scripts would access the functions above by calling `game.tick` or `game.server_time`. There are no global vars anywhere.

Now I want to switch to a `require.js`-based architecture.

So I included this:

```
<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/require.js"></script>
```

`js/main.js` is currently:

```
requirejs(["scripts/app"], function(app) {
    console.log(app);
});
```

And in `scripts/app.js` I have:

```
define(function (require) {
    var game = require('./game');
});
```

Now, the `game.tick` and `game.server_time` functions are available, but I have a problem with the `window.load` code in `game.js` not firing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `script` to load a script and do not use the `async` attribute, the script is executed immediately. So it has the opportunity to listen for the `load` event.

When you use RequireJS, the script is loaded asynchronously. And in many cases, this means that the `load` event will happen *before* your script runs, and thus before `window.addEventListener('load',...` runs. So your code is listening for an event that has *already* happened, and won't happen again.

If you already use jQuery, you can use jQuery's [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) facility. Or you can use the [`domReady`](https://github.com/requirejs/domReady) plugin for RequireJS. Both of them are able to detect the case where the `load` event has occurred already.

Comment: I just found domReady a minute ago and was trying it out, but when I follow the instructions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596886/window-onload-not-calling-function) I get an error as ['main'] is for some reason read as '/scripts/main' and that doesn't exist (the correct path being /js/scripts/main but when I try that in still doesn't work).

Comment: Anyway simply switching to `$(document).ready` did the trick, thanks.